# How to query a model two relations deep for an attribute on the final model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to perform a search for all `Collections` that contain a `Blob.item` with a title that matches the search query.

A `Collection` `belongs_to` `Blob` and `belongs_to` `User`. A `Blob` `belongs_to` `Item` and `belongs_to` `User`. An `Item` has a attribute.

```
Class Collection
  belongs_to :blob
  belongs_to :user
end

Class Blob
 belongs_to :item
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :collections, foreign_key: :collection_id
end

Class Item
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :blobs, foreign_key : :item_id

 validates :title, presence: true
end
```

I know that a basic search in my `collection.rb` should look something like this:

```
if search
 where(["blob ILIKE ? OR user ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
 else
  order('id DESC')
 end
end
```

But this doesn't work, because ILIKE is pattern matching the search parameter against `blob_id`. Clearly I need a join of some sort, but I'm having a difficult time understanding the differences/use cases of joins and includes.

If I do `Collections.joins(:blob)` I get `SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" INNER JOIN "blobs" ON "blobs"."id" = "collections"."blob_id"` which is a step in the right direction, but I'm not able to query the `Item` association that `has_many` `Blobs`, because `Item` doesn't exist on `Collection`.

So...how would I write a query that searches for the `Collection` that belongs to a `Blob` that belongs to an `Item` containing a specific attribute?

Comment: Why don't you try `ransack` gem it has association search [link](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#associations)

Comment: Because using an entire gem for an SQL query is pointless and adds a ridiculous amount of bloat and unnecessary dependency.

Comment: As you mentioned it being a search feature, i mentioned gem because in future if you wish to include multiple fields from associated item into search or add another model to search it will be time taking and difficult to debug the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `a` is an attribute in `Item` model, so query will be like this: -

```
Collection.joins(blob: :item).where("items.a LIKE ?", "%{q}%");
```

Comment: I didn't even think to do that and I'm still trying to wrap my head around how this works. But that was it! Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: @sabaeus Great to know that it works, it's a simple multilevel join with conditions. you can get many example and references. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includes` along with `references`, as this page shows: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

```
Collection.
  includes(:blob).includes(:items).
  references(:items).references(:blob).
  where('items.a LIKE ?', "%{q}%")
```

Just using `includes` will make multiple SQL queries, while just using `references` will not give you the correct Collection information.

You may have to modify this based on your exact query requirement.

Comment: Thank you! `Collection.includes(:blob).includes(:item)` results in `ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError: Association named 'item' was not found on Collection; perhaps you misspelled it?`. I want to look `item` up on `blob`, not `collection`.  Let me check this link out.

Comment: You probably need to use `items` and `blobs`. Can you try that? `references` takes the table name

Comment: Same thing. It's looking for an association `item` on `collection`, but I don't have that association defined in my model. the code you provided looks like it chains `item` to `blob` to `collection`, but it's not working the way i think it's supposed to

Comment: running the full query minus the `where` clause gets this error `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Collection' to association named 'items'; perhaps you misspelled it?`